# How to automatically capture images from URLs?

Tags: entities, media

My site is a bookmarking site where people share URLs.

First, if the page being submitted has Facebook open graph image information, Drupal should transfer that image to local files and display it (similar to sharing links on Facebook).

Otherwise, display a thumbnail preview of the page.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Opengraph filter](https://drupal.org/project/opengraph_filter) module

> When you post a link on facebook, you get a little summary of that
>   site under your comment or post (with or without thumbnail). This
>   works with OpenGraph metatags. Basicly Facebook scrapes the content of
>   the url and makes a nice little summary.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you actually looking for is the [Opengraph Filter](https://drupal.org/project/opengraph_filter) module.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on drupal modules page, I googled drupal modules screenshot but I not yet test it.

https://drupal.org/project/website_screenshot

https://drupal.org/project/pagepeeker

Comment: Neither one of these modules answer the question.